# How can I fill the canvas pixel by pixel?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, pixel

I am trying to set the colors of all the pixels on the canvas. I'm pretty sure I know how it works: first 4 values in `canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData.data` refer to the r, g, b, and a of the first pixel, second 4 go to second pixel, and so on. I would like to know what is wrong with this code:

```
function draw()
{
    var cnvs = document.getElementById("CanvasFlynn"); //Assume it's 2x2 pixels
    var cont  = cnvs.getContext("2d");
    var imdt  = cont.getImageData(0,0,2,2);
    var r     = [ 255 , 0 , 0 , 255 ];
    var g     = [ 0 , 255 , 0 , 255 ];
    var b     = [ 0 , 0 , 255 , 255 ];
    var a     = [ 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 ];
    var index = 0;
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < imdt.data.length ; i++ )
    {
        index              = 4*i;
        imdt.data[index]   = r[i];
        imdt.data[index+1] = g[i];
        imdt.data[index+2] = b[i];
        imdt.data[index+3] = a[i];
    }
}
```

If anyone could tell me why this doesn't change the canvases pixel colors, that would rock (I don't actually use a 2x2 cavas, that was just to serve as an example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bunch of issues

1. `cont.getImageData` is a function not a property
2. `imdt` isn't the canvas's image data, it's a copy of the canvas's image data.

   You need to call `cont.putImageData` to copy the data back into the canvas
3. imdt.data.length is a count of bytes not pixels. There are 4 bytes per pixel.
4. alpha is in the range of 0 to 255 in image data

```js
function draw()
{
    var cnvs = document.getElementById("CanvasFlynn"); //Assume it's 2x2 pixels
    var cont  = cnvs.getContext("2d");
    var imdt  = cont.getImageData(0, 0, 2, 2);
    var r     = [ 255 , 0 , 0 , 255 ];
    var g     = [ 0 , 255 , 0 , 255 ];
    var b     = [ 0 , 0 , 255 , 255 ];
    var a     = [ 255 , 255 ,255 ,255 ];
    var index = 0;
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < imdt.data.length / 4 ; i++ )
    {
        index              = 4*i;
        imdt.data[index]   = r[i];
        imdt.data[index+1] = g[i];
        imdt.data[index+2] = b[i];
        imdt.data[index+3] = a[i];
    }
  
    cont.putImageData(imdt, 0, 0);
}
draw();
```

```html
<p>Note the 2x2 canvas will be stretched to 100x100 and may be bilinear filtered</p>
<canvas id="CanvasFlynn" width="2" height="2"
 style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; image-rendering: pixelated;"></canvas>
```

note that it would arguable be faster to treat the data as 32bit values so then there is one value per pixel

```js
function draw()
{
    var cnvs = document.getElementById("CanvasFlynn"); //Assume it's 2x2 pixels
    var cont  = cnvs.getContext("2d");
    var imdt  = cont.getImageData(0, 0, 2, 2);
    
    // make a Uint32 view of the image data
    var pixels = new Uint32Array(imdt.data.buffer);  
    var r     = 0xFF0000FF;
    var g     = 0xFF00FF00;
    var b     = 0xFFFF0000;
    var y     = 0xFF00FFFF;
    
    pixels[0] = r;
    pixels[1] = g;
    pixels[2] = b;
    pixels[3] = y;
  
    cont.putImageData(imdt, 0, 0);
}
draw();
```

```html
<p>Note the 2x2 canvas will be stretched to 100x100 and may be bilinear filtered</p>
<canvas id="CanvasFlynn" width="2" height="2"
 style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; image-rendering: pixelated;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I did call `cont.getImageData` as a function with parameters, just forgot to include that in SO question box, fixed it. The rest of your advice though fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: You fixed OP's code, but if you're not going to use the already painted data, then it will be less expensive to use `ctx.createImageData()`